# node: command not found

Tags: apt, nodejs, npm

I don't understand why the `node` command will not work, whereas `nodejs` works:

```
$ node --version
zsh: command not found: node
$ nodejs --version
v0.10.15
```

I tried `apt-get install nodejs`, but the latest version is already installed.

And furthermore:

```
$ npm
zsh: command not found: npm
```

I thought `npm` was included in NodeJS > 0.10?

Comment: may this post solve your problem 
[Stackoverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593902/node-command-not-found

Comment: @AhmedAl-battashi It doesn't help, I have already read it. NodeJS is installed, `nodejs` is in the PATH, but `node` and `npm` aren't available, I can't find them anywhere on my system.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I do recall that the reason why the `node` binary was renamed was because it conflicted with one of the packages called `node` (Amateur Packet Radio Node Program).

Comment: Are you sure that you are looking for `node` and not `nodejs`? `node` is not what you think it is.

Comment: @Braiam `node` is used in every tutorial I've seen

Comment: It looks like the `node` package in Ubuntu will be renamed to `ax25-node`. So hopefully in the future Ubuntu will just install a binary named `node` when you install `nodejs`. @Braiam The de-facto standard shebang for node.js scripts is `#!/usr/bin/env node`, so Ubuntu sort of breaks standard node.js scripts because of its binary name conflict policy which was not respected by the node.js project.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The `node` package is unrelated to NodeJS. See here for information about [node [image: Install node]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/node):

> Amateur Packet Radio Node program (transitional package)

---

You should instead install the [`nodejs` [image: Install nodejs]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nodejs) package.

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

then use it with the `nodejs` command.

The reason `node` doesn't work is likely because of conflicts with the original `node` package linked above.

---

If you want [`npm` [image: Install npm]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/npm), you'll have to install that as well.

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Comment: I knew about the `node` package, however I don't see why a name package has any influence on the command line tool. For example, I don't install `php`, but `php5-cli`. But thanks for the answer, I was unsure if manually installing `npm` would be a problem, apparently it is not.

Comment: Installing the `nodejs-legacy` package lets you use either  `node` or `nodejs`.

Answer (score 50):

I agree, this is a bit of an issue but I don't know why it's happening.

### The Fix

First things first, just create a symbolic link from called `node` pointing to the `nodejs` binary.

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

#### The Problem

Quite a few guides I found for installing Nodejs ([here](http://blog.nodeknockout.com/post/65463770933/how-to-install-node-js-and-npm#hello) and [here](http://howtonode.org/how-to-install-nodejs#hello)) all have similar code to test whether the installation happened correctly. So essentially create a simple server like so:

```
// hello_node.js
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello Node.js\n');
}).listen(8124, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

and then run it in nodejs with the following:

```
node hello_node.js
```

And then when I was trying to use npm to install something, it was failing and reporting the same `node not found` message.

Comment: I have the same problem, sudo apt-get install npm and then following @jlouzado recomendation complete the job. Now is working well

Comment: Funny tip: there is a [nodejs-legacy](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nodejs-legacy) package that provides the symlink, purportedly for compatibility with "legacy code" that still relies on it.

Comment: @Simón I think it's a better solution than making a symbolic link.

Comment: So now I'm counting 3 packages I have to install if I'm doing basically anything with Node.js. I've been trying to install this one Node.js library for like an hour.

Comment: I was unable to install `asciicast2gif` because during installation it runs `node install.js` and I get the error `sh: 1: node: not found`. This fixes it.

Answer (score 26):

Like @minerz029 already said there is a conflict with the `node` package. But if you still need the `node` command (because a script uses only `node`for example), the correct way is to install the [`nodejs-legacy`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/nodejs-legacy) package:

```
apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

and not create a symlink on your own (especially not in `/usr/bin/`). This will provide a `node` command for nodejs.

Comment: It works. I think this is better than @jlouzado's answer.

Comment: unless you frequently "start from scratch" with your _OS_ install .... MUCH better to let apt manage symlinks in bin.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -

sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

:)

Comment: Why are you not installing the latest version?: `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -`

Comment: setup_6.x is stable

Comment: The LTS policy for Node.js version 8 is that it is pending LTS now, it starts being LTS in a few months in October, 2017, it starts maintenance period in April, 2019, and ends maintenance in December, 2019. For more information see the table in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/626383/node-package-manager-got-corrupted-in-some-way-now-it-cannot-be-installed/626388#626388

Answer (score 1):

may you need to install manually

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Comment: I read everywhere that I shouldn't install npm manually because it was included in > v0.10 :/ I'm a little lost

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix for `nvm` users. I use `nvm` (node version manager) and for me to use the `npm` command I must always issue before `npm` this command `nvm use 0.x` (replace `0.x` with `0.11` or `0.10` for example, the version you wish to use).

Answer (score 0):

[As minerz029 has already mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/a/405035/18665), certain versions of the `nodejs` package won't provide the `node` binary due to another package previously using that name. The solution is as simple as following the installatoin steps on Node's own website:

[Installing Node.js via package manager | Debian and Ubuntu based Linux distributions](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions)

At the moment, those steps are:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

But it'd be best to check the source link to make sure you're using the latest version.