# Node Package Manager got corrupted in some way, now it cannot be installed

Tags: apt, nodejs, npm

I ran into a problem today when I decided to use `npm update -g` in a nodejs app directory. This was a bad decision, because it caused me to run into a [common and disastrous problem with npm](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6110).

The solution is to reinstall nodejs and npm. Unfortunately when I go to install npm using `sudo apt-get install npm` it doesn't work.

The full error in the terminal is here:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested
an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that 
some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-ansi but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-nopt (>= 2.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What can I do to get npm properly installed and running again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Update

Regarding William Entriken's comment below this answer, there is a better way of installing Node.js natively in Ubuntu as a snap package.

Node.js is available as a snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. Specific to Node.js, developers can choose from one or more of the currently supported releases and get regular automatic updates directly from NodeSource. Node.js versions 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 and 18 are currently available, with the Snap Store being updated within hours or minutes of a Node.js release.

Node can be installed with a single command, for example:

```
sudo snap install node --classic --channel 9/stable
```

The node snap can be accessed by the command `node`, for example:

```
$ node -v  
v9.9.0
```

An up-to-date version of npm will installed as part of the node snap. npm should be run outside of the node repl, in your normal shell. After installing the node snap run the following command to enable npm update checking:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /home/your-username/.config
```

Replace  **`your-username`** in the above command with your own username. Then run `npm -v` to check if the version of npm is up-to-date. As an example I checked that npm was up-to-date, checked the version of an already installed package named yarn with the command `npm list yarn` and then updated the existing yarn package to the latest version with the command `npm update yarn`

Users can switch between versions of Node.js at any time without needing to involve additional tools like nvm (Node Version Manager), for example:

```
sudo snap refresh node --channel=8/stable
```

Users can test bleeding-edge versions of Node.js that can be installed from the latest edge channel by switching with:

```
sudo snap switch node --edge
```

This approach is only recommended for those users who are willing to participate in testing and bug reporting upstream.

---

#### Original answer

To install the latest LTS versions of Node.js (nodejs) and Package manager for Node.js (npm) in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu, open the terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs npm ## remove existing nodejs and npm packages
sudo apt-get install curl  
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

If you are copying these three commands, don't neglect the hyphen at the end of the second command.

The `nodejs` package contains the `nodejs` binary as well as `npm`, so you don't need to install `npm` separately. However, in order for some `npm` packages to work (such as those that require building from source), you will need to install the `build-essential` package:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

#### LTS Plan

New semver-major releases of Node.js are cut from `master` every six months. New even-numbered versions (e.g. v6, v8, v10, etc.) are cut in April. New odd-numbered versions (e.g. v5, v7, v9) are cut in October.

When a new odd-numbered major release is cut, the previous even-numbered major version transitions to the Long Term Support plan.

Every major version covered by the LTS plan will be actively maintained for a period of 18 months from the date it enters LTS coverage. Following those 18 months of active support, the major version will transition into "maintenance" mode for 12 additional months.

#### non-LTS installation

Current to March, 2017 the commands to install the latest non-LTS version of Node.js (v8 at the time this was posted) are as follows:

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs npm ## remove existing nodejs and npm packages
sudo apt-get install curl  
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

#### Node.js LTS schedule

| Release | Status | Codename | Initial release | LTS Start | Maintenance Start | Maintenance End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6.x | EOL | Boron | 2016-04-26 | 2016-10-18 | 2018-04-30 | 2019-04-30 |
| 7.x | EOL |  | 2017-05-30 |  |  | 2017-06-30 |
| 8.x | EOL | Carbon | 2016-10-25 | 2017-10-31 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-12-31 |
| 9.x | EOL |  | 2017-10-01 |  |  | 2018-06-30 |
| 10.x | EOL | Dubnium | 2018-04-24 | 2018-10-30 | 2020-05-19 | 2021-04-30 |
| 11.x | EOL |  | 2018-10-23 |  |  | 2019-06-01 |
| 12.x | Maintenance LTS | Erbium | 2019-04-23 | 2019-10-21 | 2020-11-301 | 2022-04-30 |
| 13.x | EOL |  | 2019-10-22 |  |  | 2020-06-01 |
| 14.x | Maintenance LTS | Fermium | 2020-04-21 | 2020-10-27 | 2021-10-30 | 2023-04-30 |
| 16.x | Active LTS | Gallium | 2021-04-20 | 2021-10-26 | 2022-10-18 | 2024-04-30 |
| 17.x | Current |  | 2021-10-19 |  | 2022-04-01 | 2022-06-01 |
| 18.x | Current |  | 2022-04-19 | 2022-10-25 | 2023-10-18 | 2025-04-30 |

Comment: [Node.js Long Term Support Release Schedule](https://github.com/nodejs/LTS/)

Comment: using "sudo apt-get install -y nodejs  " worked for me

Comment: This method requires trusting MANY parties and then giving full access to your computer to deb.nodesource.com, an entity that can't even be bothered to update their website each version to include the content hash for your security. No thanks!

Comment: @WilliamEntriken Node.js is now a snap package in Ubuntu that does not require running the `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -` command. Instead Node.js can be installed as a snap package. I added a new **Update** section to my answer which contains the instructions for installing the Node.js snap package.