# How to Install python-node in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, nodejs

I got the following results when trying to install python-node in Ubuntu 18.04.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-node
```

Answer (score 2):

Node.js does not depend on Python. To install the [node snap package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626383/node-package-manager-got-corrupted-in-some-way-now-it-cannot-be-installed/626388#626388) open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install node --classic --channel 11/stable
```

python-node is a Node.js script runner for Python. To install python-node open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip  
python3 -m pip install --user python-node
```

Both Node.js and Python can run scripts interactively in a REPL. A read–eval–print loop (REPL), also termed an interactive top level or language shell, is a simple, interactive computer programming environment that takes single user inputs (i.e. single expressions), evaluates them, and returns the result to the user. Installing IPython (*python3-ipython*) allows the user to run blocks of code and scripts interactively in a more user-friendly way.