# Run nodejs installed as snap package

Tags: apt, snap, nodejs

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and want to install a specific version of node using snap. I have installed this version successfully but when I run

```
node --version
```

I get the version I have installed using apt. How can I get it to use the node executables installed with snap and not the ones in '/usr/bin'? I've tried adding the path to the snap install to the PATH variable but it keeps picking the one installed by apt. I tried purging the the apt install but that didn't work because of reasons, and I kind of feel I shouldn't have to. Any suggestions? I can run node with:

```
snap run node
```

but what I wan't is when typing

```
> node
```

it should use the snap install. And when I run:

```
> which node
```

it should resolve to something like '/snap/nodejs/current/bin' and not '/usr/bin/node'

Comment: I have no problem running the snap app. But I have to run the whole command 'snap run node', and I can't just call 'node' and have it use the version I want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node Package Manager got corrupted in some way, now it cannot be installed](https://askubuntu.com/q/626383/). - `sudo snap switch node --channel=mychannel`

Comment: I don't find the 'redundant' answers that got this Question closed fully redundant, so here we go: `sudo apt-get --purge remove node`  `sudo snap remove node`  `sudo snap install node --classic` (open new terminal window) `node -v` DONE :)