# Having Upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04, Node, NPM, and Angular Are Not Recognized!

Tags: apt, upgrade, 20.04, nodejs, npm

I installed node, npm, and angular on Ubuntu 19.10 by using a NodeSource PPA:

```
sudo apt install curl 
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo npm install --global @angular/cli@9.0.0-rc.14
```

and it worked correctly until I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04. After trying to create a new angular project, it said:

```
/usr/bin/env: 'node': No such file or directory
```

I tried to get node, npm, and angular versions but it said they were not installed. Then I typed:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

in order to see what would happen as I had already installed them all:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW package will be installed:
nodejs
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove, and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 18.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 92.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x focal/main amd64 nodejs amd64 12.18.0
-deb-1nodesource1 [18.0 MB]
Fetched 18.0 MB in 1min 9s (260 KB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package nodejs.
(Reading database ... 162832 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack ... /nodejs_12.18.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (12.18.0-deb-1nodesource1) ...
Setting up nodejs (12.18.0-deb-1nodesource1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1)
```

This way I solved the problem and angular is now recognized on my machine but remain two questions:

1. Why did this happen after having upgraded Ubuntu?
2. And how could I have fixed it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node Package Manager got corrupted in some way, now it cannot be installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626383/node-package-manager-got-corrupted-in-some-way-now-it-cannot-be-installed) + afterwards install angular/cli in the usual way

Comment: @karel Thanks for your suggestion, I solved my problem the way I explained in my post. But I want to know why the problem cropped up?

Comment: You'll have much fewer problems if you use the Ubuntu Software app to install software instead of following bad advice from blogs and YouTube. That's how you could have fixed it. The reason why it happened is resistance to change. Someone posted some obsolete advice on Ask Ubuntu 7 years ago and Ubuntu users are going to be chained to it for it for the next 20 years.