# Angular CLI vs AngularJS

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I'm not understanding if there are differences between Angular CLI and JS because when i search for the installation I just found the one for Angular CLI.

Comment: If you think this software installation with multiple dependencies question is not about Ubuntu read the answer first before reviewing it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Prerequisites

To install Angular on your local system, you need the following:

- Node.js

  Angular requires a current, active LTS, or maintenance LTS version of Node.js. To install Node.js run either `sudo apt install nodejs` or `sudo snap install node --classic`. To learn a few commands for the node snap package, for example how to select one of multiple installed Node.js versions see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/626388/).

  For information about specific version requirements, see the engines key in the [package.json](https://unpkg.com/@angular/cli/package.json) file.

  If you are unsure what version of Node.js runs on your system, run `node -v` in a terminal window.
- npm package manager

  Angular, the Angular CLI, and Angular applications depend on npm packages for many features and functions. To download and install npm packages, you need an npm package manager. To install npm run `sudo apt install npm`. To check that you have the npm client installed, run `npm -v` in a terminal window.

#### Install the Angular CLI

➡ You use the Angular CLI to create projects, generate application and library code, and perform a variety of ongoing development tasks such as testing, bundling, and deployment.

To install the Angular CLI, open a terminal window and run the following command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

#### Create a workspace and initial application

You develop apps in the context of an Angular [workspace](https://angular.io/guide/glossary#workspace).

To create a new workspace and initial starter app:

1. Run the CLI command ng new and provide the name my-app, as shown here:

   ```
   ng new my-app
   ```
2. The `ng new` command prompts you for information about features to include in the initial app. Accept the defaults by pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd>  key.

The Angular CLI installs the necessary Angular npm packages and other dependencies. This can take a few minutes.

The CLI creates a new workspace and a simple Welcome app, ready to run.

> You also have the option to use Angular's strict mode, which can help you write better, more maintainable code. For more information, see [Strict mode](https://angular.io/guide/strict-mode).

<sub>**Source:** revised from [Angular - Setting up the local environment and workspace](https://angular.io/guide/setup-local)</sub>