# $ node -v results nothing

Tags: nodejs

I have installed node using `sudo apt-get install node`.

```
linux@linux:~$ node -v
linux@linux:~$

linux@linux:~$ npm -v
1.3.10
linux@linux:~$
```

I also download node from https://nodejs.org/en/ but, I don't find the full installation manual.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/

Comment: @VladSpirin where the installation guide? your provided guide is started with `How do I start with Node.js after I installed it?`

Comment: https://tecadmin.net/install-latest-nodejs-npm-on-ubuntu/

Comment: You didn't install it. Try `sudo apt-get install nodejs`

Comment: @VladSpirin this add nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The Node.js executable is installed to `/usr/bin/nodejs` and the command to show the Node.js version is:

```
nodejs -v
```

Instead of installing the Node.js apt package with `sudo apt install nodejs` I recommend installing the more up-to-date Node.js snap package with `sudo snap install node` by following the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm/594657#594657).

Comment: @SurajRao `node -v` is the command for showing the Node.js version for the  Node.js snap package. For showing the Node.js apt package version see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm

Comment: Yeah . You are right.. actually https://askubuntu.com/questions/404929/node-command-not-found explains it... Sorry.. Ubuntu has some package name issue

Comment: The reason for this discrepancy is that it is possible to install the Node.js snap package and the Node.js apt package alongside each other, and still be able to check the versions of each package in an unambiguous way. btw Your duplicate comment below the question is correct. The question is a legitimate duplicate of [How to install the latest versions of NodeJS and NPM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm)

Comment: that makes sense.. But for people who want to maintain multiple node installations, it is recommended to use nvm.

Comment: nvm is now unnecessary if the Node.js snap package is installed. Users can switch between versions of Node.js at any time without needing to involve additional tools like nvm (Node Version Manager), for example: `sudo snap refresh node --channel=8/stable` It's a great feature, you can have multiple Node.js versions installed alongside each other with the Node.js snap package, and select which version of Node.js to use for each project.